# To remove namespaces and parent nodes from a xml by using XSLT

Tags: xslt

I want to remove namespaces and parent nodes from a xml by using XSLT.

The below mentioned is the source and target xml.kindly help me.

```
    ****Source.xml****

<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <soapenv:Body>
       <ns2:completeProductionPlan xmlns="http://ServiceManagement/OIS_Services_v01.00/common"
            xmlns:ns2="http://ServiceManagement/TechnicalOrderManagement/ProductionFulfillment_v01.00/types">
        <ns2:messageID>
            <value>9133235059913398501_9133235059913398860</value>
        </ns2:messageID>
    </ns2:completeProductionPlan>
    </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>


****Target****

<completeProductionPlan >
<MessageId>9133235059913398501_9133235059913398860</MessageId>
</completeProductionPlan>
```

**namespace_Remove.xsl**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name(.)}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:attribute name="{local-name(.)}">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Can you show the XSLT you've tried so far and how it's output differs from what you need? There are many other questions you can refer to on Stack Overflow discussing similar situations to this so presumably you have made some sort of start yourself?

Comment: Actually am able to remove the namespace from the XML.But unable to remove the parent root tags from XML in the same xsl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XSLT you have so far will remove namespaces from the XML but it won't change the structure.  For that you need to add some additional templates, remembering that the match and select expressions in the stylesheet have to operate against the original input XML with namespaces, not the no-namespace version you're producing.

So first you need to add some namespace declarations to the `xsl:stylesheet`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
            xmlns:ns2="http://ServiceManagement/TechnicalOrderManagement/ProductionFulfillment_v01.00/types"
            xmlns:common="http://ServiceManagement/OIS_Services_v01.00/common"
            exclude-result-prefixes="soap ns2 common">
```

And now you can add suitable templates:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <!-- ignore everything except the first child element of the Body -->
  <xsl:apply-templates select="soap:Envelope/soap:Body/*[1]" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ns2:messageID">
  <MessageID><xsl:value-of select="common:value" /></MessageID>
</xsl:template>
```

Of course, for this particular example you could use a much simpler stylesheet structure, hard-coding the output format in one template and just pulling out the message ID value from the original XML, but it's good to get used to the more generic style of XSLT programming when you start to need to deal with more complex formats.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ian, I got the result now.